# How to set a custom HTTP status code from inside OpenCPU R function

Tags: r, apache, opencpu, rapache

I have an R function on OpenCPU (provided from OpenCPU docker image: https://hub.docker.com/r/opencpu/rstudio/) which filters data by some criterias. If there is no data to return I want to send a message (No data) with 204 status code. How can I set status status code from inside the R function?

There is information in rApache documentation (http://rapache.net/manual.html). It is said there is a function setStatus() in rApache, but I couldn't set status code when calling this function. I tried to set 204 status code, but I get a default (for POST) 201 status code instead.

```r
filterData <- function(filter_a = NULL, filter_b = NULL) {

  data <- as.data.frame(
    list("a" = c(1,2,3), "b" = c(3,2,1))
  )

  if (!is.null(filter_a)) {
    data <- subset(data, a == filter_a)
  }

  if (!is.null(filter_b)) {
    data <- subset(data, b == filter_b)
  }

  if (nrow(data) == 0) {
    setStatus(204L)
    return("No content")
  } else {
    return(data)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: this is not possible.

The logic for setting the response status codes is encapsulated within openCPU. Status codes are managed within the *res* object. In case of POST requests openCPU will overwrite the status code in *session_eval* even if you would manage to set the status code in the internal object. OpenCPU would overwrite it with 201 Code after executing your custom code.